# vCenter "Recent Tasks" pane: How to make "Pick columns" customization persistent

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

Everytime I login to vCenter the first thing I do is uncheck a few columns in `Recent Tasks > Pick columns`. The vCenter just cannot remember my choice which is quite frustrating. Is there any way to make the customization persistent?

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can make this option persistent. It should be a per user setting, so the only place would be in the personal preferences.

The column settings in the Task Console are persistent, but not in the Recent Tasks list.

Comment: sigh. the *Recent Tasks* and *Task Console* can simply share the same settings right? or it's also ok to save the customization in browser cookie. never understand why vmware cannot make the ui more modern.